# Studying Geodesic Deviation and Tidal Forces

Tags: geodesic, general-relativity

I have been studying general relativity from a mathematical point of view and I was wondering what would be a good material (lecture notes, books, and so on) to study geodesic deviation and tidal forces with a strong mathematical (differential geometric) framework?

Comment: Why not [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019) ? A larger version of this you can buy as a book.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, @KurtG.! I will study the lecture notes.

Comment: Maybe check out [A Mathematical Introduction to General Relativity][1] ?

  [1]: https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/12454 

It is targeted to mathematics students (at advanced undergraduate/beginning graduate level). A preview of the contents and a sample chapter can be seen at the website above. In particular, it gives an introductory pure mathematical (differential geometric) treatment of geodesic deviation and tidal forces.